# Как сделать таймер обратного отсчета?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как реализовать таймер обратного отсчета для сайта, чтобы счётчик сбрасывался каждый день?

Comment: Классный вариант использовать cookie или localstorage. Даём печеньку на сутки. Если пиченьки нет или время истекло – стартуем таймер заново

Comment: И, пожалуй, метка должна быть [tag:javascript]

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе масса неясностей, ну например самое простое:

```
var t = Date.now() + 1000*60*60*24; // Надо сохранить
if (Date.now() < t) {
    alert('Осталось: ' + (t - Date.now()));
} else {
    alert('Время истекло');
}
```

Comment: (отсутсвующий) таймер будет показывать каждому посетителю сайта что-то своё?

Comment: @Sergiks В ТЗ ничего об этом нет.

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, нужно указать какое-то одно время суток, до которого считает таймер, и в которое он сбрасывается на `23:59:59`

```js
// локальное время, 
// до которого таймер считает,
// и когда сбрасывается
var resetAt = '03:00'; // HH:MM
resetAt = resetAt.split(':');
if( resetAt.length !== 2) throw "Bad time format";
resetAt = resetAt.map(function(e){return parseInt(e);});
var el = document.getElementById('out');

function countDown() {
  var D = new Date();
  var h = resetAt[0] - D.getHours();
  var m = resetAt[1] - D.getMinutes() - 1;
  var s = 60 - D.getSeconds() - 1;
  if( m < 0) {
    m += 60;
    h--;
  }
  if( h < 0) h += 24;
  h = ('0'+h).slice(-2);
  m = ('0'+m).slice(-2);
  s = ('0'+s).slice(-2);
  el.innerText = ''+ h+ ':'+ m+ ':'+ s;
}

countDown();
window.setInterval( countDown, 200);
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: По-моему это называется часы.

Comment: @Khipster песочные. Я понял задачу ТС вот так. У вас другая идея?